# 2 errors - Cannot implicitly convert type system.collection.generic.list<float> to float and cannot implicitly convert type float [] to float

Tags: c#

Showing error `Cannot implicitly convert type system.collection.generic.list<float> to float` in line `"return storerandomvalue;"` and its type is

```
List<float> storerandomvalues = new List<float>(100);
```

the storerandomvalues is a list with size of 100.

```
        public float Update_Au(int itemid)
            {
                List<float> minus = new List<float>(100);
                List<float> Landa_Au = new List<float>(100);
                //float[] Error_Bi = b[itemid];
                float[] Error_Bi =new float [100];
                for (int iii=0;iii<100;iii++)
                {
                    Landa_Au[iii]=Convert.ToSingle(storerandomvalues[iii]*0.1);
                }
                for (int cc = 0; cc < 100; cc++)
                {
                    Error_Bi[cc] = Convert.ToSingle(i_f[cc] * error);
                }
                for (int ccc = 0; ccc < 100; ccc++)
                {
                    minus[ccc] = Error_Bi[ccc] - Landa_Au[ccc];
                }
                for (int ee = 0; ee < 100; ee++)
                {
                    minus[ee] = Convert.ToSingle(minus[ee] * 0.1);
                }
                for (int h = 0; h < 100; h++)
                {
                    storerandomvalues[h] = storerandomvalues[h] + minus[h];
                }
                return storerandomvalues;  // Linee's error
            }
```

Showing error `"cannot implicitly convert type float []  to float"` in line `return i_f1;` and its type is `float[] i_f = new float[100];`

```
public float Update_Bi(int itemid)
        {
            List<float> minus1 = new List<float>(100);
            List<float> Landa_Bi = new List<float>(100);
            float[] Error_Au = new float [100];
            for (int iz=0;iz<100;iz++)
            {
                Landa_Bi[iz]=Convert.ToSingle(i_f[iz]*0.1);
            }
            for (int ix = 0; ix < 100; ix++)
            {
                Error_Au[ix] = storerandomvalues[ix] * error;
            }
            for (int ic = 0; ic < 100; ic++)
            {
                minus1[ic] = Error_Au[ic] - Landa_Bi[ic];
            }
            for (int ie = 0; ie < 100; ie++)
            {
                minus1[ie] = Convert.ToSingle(minus1[ie] * 0.1);
            }
            for (int ih = 0; ih < 100; ih++)
            {
                i_f1[ih] = i_f[ih] + minus1[ih];
            }
            return i_f1;
        }
```

Comment: `float` is not `List<float>` and `float` is not `float[]`, look at what you return from your methods and decide what the caller should expect

Comment: What is the use of `itemid` parameter?

Comment: Your mom tells you: Give me one apple. You give her a basket. Are you sure a basket is what she asked for? Next time before posting such question, think twice about the error message.

Comment: itemid is an integer which is inserted to application and based on that ,I call this method @dasblinkenlight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem 1:** you have declared your function  `Update_Au()` return type as `float` but you are trying to return the `List<float>`

**Solution 1:** change `Update_Au()` function `return` type from `float` to `List<float>`. function.

**Problem 2:** you have declared your function `Update_Bi()` return type as `float` but you are tyring to return the `float[]`

**Solution 2:** change `Update_Bi()` function return type from `float` to `float[]`.